# How do I implement WebView tabs in Android Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-webview

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this without utilizing a LazyRow of WebViews? When using this method, the WebViews automatically reload every time you switch to that tab, thereby defeating the purpose of having tabs. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could approach this?

I attempted to address the issue by using a database to store the tab URLs and implementing a LazyRow to display the WebViews.

Comment: You can save state of the screen and achieve this using TabRow

Comment: can you share more detail what you tried and how you want more specific with image?